# Translate my calculated x-y co-ordinates to on screen co-ordinates android

Tags: android, coordinates

I am trying to  implement a projectile motion by plotting the points on the screen  of my app.I need to scale the calculated co-ordinates  and at the same time I also need to know the range of X-Y co-ordinates visible on my screen so that my final calculated co-ordinates fits on visible screen

How do I found the range of co-ordinates?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class (which you should use), then you can use the methods

```
getHeight()
getWidth()
getDensity()
```

those will give you height, width and density of the canvas.

Comment: I have the screen's width and height .I need to find the x-y co-ordinate plane's range on canvas(screen) so that I can scale my points and plot on it.. i.e cartesian co-ordinates

Comment: The getHeight() method will return the range you have in the y-direction and the getWidth() method will return the range you have in the x-direction so what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks!!! One of the issue I am facing is that the y co-ordinates are coming negative as I am trying to plot the points on trajectory.How do I handle that and how to perform translation of calculated co=ordinates to android's on scree co-ordinates

Comment: In which range are your coordinates?

Comment: sample points are: (51.0177704,-403.99307) ,(561.19476,-58343.92) .These are results of x and y displacement calculated through the equation for trajectory(in projectile motion)

Comment: Do you have any maximum and minimum values of x and y direction?

Comment: That's again another issue.To plot the trajectory I  need to make certain assumtion.Right now am making assumption for the initial velocity to be 100.Based on that my minimum value comes out to be : Value of mX1: -492.88098
Value of mY1: -58306.605